# Can the objectGUID be specified on creation or changed afterward?

Tags: active-directory, ad-lds

Our system links users in an LDAP store to users in a SQL database. The database has been around longer than the LDAP store though, and we'd like to bring pre-existing users from the database into LDAP.

We would like to specify the objectGUID when migrating existing users to match their existing GUID in the database, but as far as I can see there is not an easy way (or possibly no way at all) to do this or to modify it after the record has been created in LDAP.

Can anyone tell me how to specify or modify the objectGUID, or else confirm that it cannot be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.  The objectGuid never changes and cannot be specified.  Think of it as an identity key or database-generated.

Object-Guid attribute
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx