# How Object-GUID replicated

Tags: active-directory, domain, replication, attributes

since Object-GUID is a non replicated attribute, then how All DCs have same object-GUID for an object?

how object-GUID is replicated to all DC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't need to be replicated. It is replicated as part of the object during creation. It is the primary key of the object in the Active Directory database, and cannot changed or removed so there is never a case where it would need to be replicated.

[Can the objectGUID be specified on creation or changed afterward?](https://serverfault.com/questions/641945/can-the-objectguid-be-specified-on-creation-or-changed-afterward)